# Extraer fechas con spaCy

Tags: python, xml, spacy

Tengo archivos XML a los cuales debo extraerle las fechas de una cita, tengo dos casos:

```
<author>MARTIN DE SAINT-GILLES</author>, Comment. Amphorismes Ypocras,1362-1363, p.109.

<author>ANON.</author>, Grant herbier[Secrets de Salerne], XVe s., p.36.
```

La salida que deseo es:

```
1362, 1363, XV
```

El codigo (siguiendo el ejemplo del sitio de spaCy, ya que soy novata) es este:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

La salida que tengo es:

```
MARTIN DE SAINT ORG
Amphorismes Ypocras,1362 PER 
Grant herbier[Secrets PER
Salerne LOC
XVe LOC
```

Pone la fecha junto a algo mas y solo una, cuando hay dos
¿Alguna idea para obtener todas las fechas, independientemente que sean numeros arabigos o romanos?

Comment: No conozco spacy, pero al ser un engine de NLP imagino que PER debería corresponder a la entidad identificada (Person?), así como LOC podría ser Location? El tema con esto, imagino, es que seguramente deberías entrenar previamente un modelo para identificar las fecha, no creo que haya algo ya preparado para esto. Si los formatos fueran medianamente estándar podría buscar una aproximación más básica, usando expresiones regulares o algún código "ad-hoc"